# Configuring a standalone application for JTA and JPA with Spring

Tags: spring, jpa

I have a standalone application that uses JPA. I want to configure it as in section 13.5 of the manual. That part of the manual is piece-meal when it comes to explaining what has to be in the configuration .xml file.  I've worked through several problems, but now I'm blocked by the Exception below complaining about the LoadTimeWeaver, which I've specified per the manual.

The Exception and my configuration file are below.

Has anyone gotten the example in section 13.5 configured and working?

Also, is there sample code to go along with the manual? That would help a lot.

Thanks.

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationExce ption: Error creating bean with name 'loadTimeWeaver': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:spring-agent.jar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <context:load-time-weaver/>
    <bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" >
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
                <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver"/>
          </property>
      </bean>

    <bean id="appraisalBusiness"  class="business.AppraisalBusiness">
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql:eqg"/>
        <property name="username" value="eqg"/>
        <property name="password" value="eqg"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="allServiceMethods" expression="execution(* business.*.*(..))"/>
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="defaultTransactionAdvice" pointcut-ref="allServiceMethods"/>
    </aop:config>

    <tx:advice id="defaultTransactionAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method
                    name="*"
                    isolation="DEFAULT"
                    propagation="REQUIRED"
                    no-rollback-for="java.lang.RuntimeException"
                    timeout="100"/>
            <tx:method
                    name="get*"
                    read-only="true"/>
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>

</beans>
```

Comment: Have you tried `-javaagent:spring-agent.jar`, as the exception suggests?

Comment: And what does `[jta]` have to do with this?

Comment: JTA is one of the Tx managers available in Spring.  It might have been better to call this transaction management instead of JTA.